# RPC Error with Geocoder

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

After several days to learn how Android works, I decided to build my first App : A simple app which displays the GMap from a address provided by the user with a simple `EditText` widget.
I use `Geocoder` to do that.

After a little bugtracking with logcat, here is the exception returned by adb :

```
E/LocationMasfClient(   53): forwardGeocode(): RPC failed with status 1
W/System.err(  262): java.io.IOException: RPC failed with status 1
W/System.err(  262):    at   android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocationName(Geocoder.java:166)
W/System.err(  262):    at fr.meetopia.tinymap.MapViewActivity.testGeoCoder(MapViewActivity.java:104)
W/System.err(  262):    at fr.meetopia.tinymap.MapViewActivity.onCreate(MapViewActivity.java:38)
W/System.err(  262):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
W/System.err(  262):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
W/System.err(  262):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
W/System.err(  262):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
W/System.err(  262):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
```

And now here is the code pointed by the stack trace :

```
Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(this);
MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    MapController mc = mapView.getController();
    GeoPoint p;
    try {
        List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName("paris france", 50);
        if (addresses.size() > 0) {
            p = new GeoPoint(
                    (int) (addresses.get(0).getLatitude() * 1E6), 
                    (int) (addresses.get(0).getLongitude() * 1E6));
            mc.animateTo(p);    
            mapView.invalidate();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Obviously, this code is a portion of a `MapActivity` instantiation.

I made some tests with different versions of Google APIS (8, 7, 4) and different versions of 
SDK platform (2.2, 2.1, 1.6), but no luck. I just noticed that the Google API 8 contains a known bug and returned a `Service Unavailable Exception` instead of `RPC Failed 1`.

On the other hand, I tried to run my app directly on my device (HTC Desire 2.1) and I noticed the same behavior (that is to say: no behavior, a Map with USA in its center).

Here comes the user-permission of the Android Manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Did you manage to find the cause of this? I am having the exact same problem!

Comment: Did you correctly set the API key for Google maps? You cannot use Geocoding without using Google Maps also. For the key see here http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/android/maps-api-signup.html

Comment: Have you checked to ensure that your geocoding service is present?  e.g. geocoder.isPresent() returns true?

Answer (score 3):

Please visit my post
[Can't mark while showing the current location in 'mapview'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9990209/cant-mark-while-showing-the-current-location-in-mapview)
I think with some prior modification you can be able to do whatever you aim for.

Answer (score 2):

I think, there are two reasons for you.

1. Didn't test, but Geocoder will still be unavailable when running in simulator. Even if geocoder.isPresent() returns true. There are workaround in the web, just read [Issue 8816 - android](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8816) for getFromLocationName( .. ) in Comment 21 and it's attached [ReverseGeocoder.java](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/attachmentText?id=8816&aid=-9179841478848829245&name=ReverseGeocode.java&token=5b4fa0ac90429947339cf4740e3d66a3)
2. Like Stefan said: When launched on device there the api-key is needed. Has to be added in the layout.xml of your mapview.

Best way to create and test a mapview for me was to implement it like normal and log and try the workaround if "Service not Available".equals( exception.getMessage() ).

Answer (score 1):

Thats my geocoding function, its working fine on google API 7. Hope its helpful

```
public GeoPoint geoCoding(String name){
         Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault() );   
         GeoPoint p = null;
            try {
                List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(
                    name, 5);
                if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                    p = new GeoPoint(
                            (int) (addresses.get(0).getLatitude() * 1E6), 
                            (int) (addresses.get(0).getLongitude() * 1E6));

                }    
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return p;
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

The Geocoder class is buggy. It works wierd at times.
I recommend not to use for getting location. Instead Local Search API and Location manager for using location services.