# Can't mark while showing the current location in 'mapview'

Tags: android, google-maps, gsp

Hear is my [project](http://www.mediafire.com/?i3ftylbjfw176o5)

In my project I am showing my current location,showing the current lat-long.But I'm not able 
to mark my current position in android.

Thnx in advance.

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d(TAG, "onLocationChanged with location " + location.toString());
    // Displays lat, long, altitude and bearing
    String text = String.format("Lat:\t %f\nLong:\t %f\nAlt:\t %f\nBearing:\t %f", location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), location.getAltitude(), location.getBearing());
    this.locationText.setText(text);

    try {
        // This gets a list of addresses 
        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), 
                location.getLongitude(), 10);
        for (Address address : addresses) {
            this.locationText.append("\n" + "kaushik");
        }

        // Convert latitude and longitude into int that the GeoPoint constructor can understand
        int latitude = (int)(location.getLatitude() * 1000000);
        int longitude = (int)(location.getLongitude() * 1000000);

        point = new GeoPoint(latitude,longitude);
        mapController.animateTo(point);
        mapController.setZoom(16);

        MapOverlay mapOverLay=new MapOverlay();
        mapOverLay.setPointToDraw(point);
        List<Overlay> listOfOverlays=map.getOverlays();
        listOfOverlays.clear();
        listOfOverlays.add(mapOverLay);

        map.invalidate();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("LocateMe", "Could not get Geocoder data", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: paste your code so that we can make changes

Comment: @Agarwal I already uplded my project.

Comment: better if can paste your sinppet here will use full to others also in future

Comment: @kaushik -- Can you explain little bit more I downloaded your project but couldn't able to find anything about current location

Comment: I mean,I am showing the current lat-long.using this function.Now I want to put my image on the location pointed by latitude & longitude.

Comment: In a word I just want a marker or an icon to be shown on my current lat-long i,e position in mapview.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mapController.animateTo(point);
mapController.setZoom(16);
MapOverlay mapOverLay=new MapOverlay();
mapOverLay.setPointToDraw(point);
List<Overlay> listOfOverlays=map.getOverlays();
listOfOverlays.clear();
listOfOverlays.add(mapOverLay);
```

Replace the above lines with below lines//where lat and long are fetched from gps.

```
Drawable srcdrawable = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pin_blue);
CustomItemizedOverlay srcitemizedOverlay = new CustomItemizedOverlay(srcdrawable, getApplicationContext());
GeoPoint srcpoint = new GeoPoint((int)( Double.parseDouble(lat) * 1E6),(int)( Double.parseDouble(lng)* 1E6));
OverlayItem srcoverlayitem = new OverlayItem(srcpoint, "Hello!", "This is your Location.");
srcitemizedOverlay.addOverlay(srcoverlayitem);
mapView.getOverlays().clear();
mapView.getOverlays().add(srcitemizedOverlay);
mapController.animateTo(srcpoint);
mapController.setZoom(16);
```

//If you want more than one point on map
/*

```
Drawable srcdrawable = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pin_blue);
CustomItemizedOverlay srcitemizedOverlay = new CustomItemizedOverlay(srcdrawable, getApplicationContext());
forloop(setoflocations){
GeoPoint srcpoint = new GeoPoint((int)( Double.parseDouble(lat) * 1E6),(int)( Double.parseDouble(lng)* 1E6));
OverlayItem srcoverlayitem = new OverlayItem(srcpoint, "Hello!", "This is your Location.");
if(srcitemizedOverlay!=null && mapController!=null){
srcitemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
mapController.animateTo(point);
animatePoint = point;
}
}
mapView.getOverlays().clear();
mapView.getOverlays().add(srcitemizedOverlay);
```

*/

also use the below CustomItemizedOverlay.java class

```
public class CustomItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {

    private final ArrayList<OverlayItem> mapOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();

    private Context context;

    public CustomItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker) {
        super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
    }

    public CustomItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
        this(defaultMarker);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
        return mapOverlays.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return mapOverlays.size();
    }

    public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
        mapOverlays.add(overlay);
        this.populate();
    }

}
```

Comment: another thng to ask,how can i mark another 4-5 location using their lat-long in the map.

Comment: its up to you whether to use it or not. using it it will navigate to last lat and long. Thats all....also +1 for you query which will be usefull for others thats why i described it breifly

Answer (score 0):

add overlay Icon on current location

```
 myItemizedOverlay.addItem(point , "myPoint1", "myPoint1");
             m_mapView.getOverlays().add(myItemizedOverlay);

mapController.animateTo(point);
```