# how to show my current location with marker on google map in android

Tags: android

please help. i have tried a code which should give my current location with marker on google map. but it is not working. i have give my location via DDMS and TELNET but still in dark. what should i do?? the code is:

```
package com.chupamobile.android.googlemaps;

import android.location.Location;

public class GoogleMapsActivity extends MapActivity{
    private MapView myMap;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        myMap = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mymap);
        initMap();
        initMyLocation();
    }

    /**
     * Initialise the map and adds the zoomcontrols to the LinearLayout.
     */
    private void initMap() {
        //myMap = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mymap);

        View zoomView = myMap.getZoomControls();
        //MapController mc = myMap.getController();
        //mc.setZoom(16);
        LinearLayout myzoom = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myzoom);
        myzoom.addView(zoomView);
        myMap.displayZoomControls(true);

    }

    /**
     * Initialises the MyLocationOverlay and adds it to the overlays of the map
     */
    private void initMyLocation() {

        MyLocationOverlay myLocOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, myMap);
        myLocOverlay.enableMyLocation();
        myLocOverlay.enableCompass();
        myMap.getOverlays().add(myLocOverlay);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I am In"+myLocOverlay, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }

    /*public void onLocationChanged(Location location){
        if(location!=null){
            GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)(location.getLatitude()*1E6),(int)(location.getLongitude()*1E6));
            MapController mc = myMap.getController();
            mc.animateTo(point);
            mc.setZoom(16);
        }

    }
*/ 

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a 4 part Youtube [Tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lywa-2-lQCg&feature=edu&list=PL2F07DBCDCC01493A) by Thenewboston, that goes through practically every part of the api, pining location etc.  each video is about 5min each, its pretty easy to follow, I think he talks about pinning location in the second video.  Also I found that the accepted answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266000/google-maps-api-not-placing-marker-at-fine-location) question may help guide you in the right direction as well.

Comment: thank u for your support. but one question, is the total procedure, i wrote above, is wrong or am i missing something?? @The Tokenizer

Comment: Ill check it out this weekend if nobody gives a solid answer by then.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.chupamobile.android.googlemaps"
    android:versionCode="100"
    android:versionName="1.0.0" >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

Comment: <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".GoogleMapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
      <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    </application>
</manifest>

Answer (score 0):

Have you put this permissions `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/> and <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` in your manifest? And have selected the Google APIs in your project->properties-> Android? Also have you got your MD5 certificate? For a complete official tutorial look here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/hello-mapview

Comment: yes i have. i have done all the thing u have said. the app shows the google map but when i give the lan and lat via DDMS or TELNET, the app does not respond. @Dinesh Venkata

Answer (score 0):

Downad full working demo :

http://www.filedropper.com/androidopenstreetmapview120516a

If map is not display in emulator or mobile device then change Map API key .